# How to generate report for JaCoCo when used as Java Agent ?

Tags: jacoco

I had configured JaCoCo in WebSphere as JavaAgent (Refer: http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html).

Restarted the server, and ran a series of automated tests on the application (to give some load) and then stopped the server.

I can see the jacoco.exec getting generated in the Server (as configured to /tmp/ location).

Now, How do I generate the HTML report ?

Before voting down this question or marking it as duplicate, here is the reason why I'm posting this question. I went through the JaCoCo Documentation like http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html and also multiple StackOverflow questions but still I'm confused.

What I understood is that the Maven plugin allows us to run the Unit tests, Integration tests and then generate a report.

What I'm looking for is a report based on the load I had given to my application deployed in Websphere. I can see the jacoco.exec file generated, but not sure from the documentation on how to generate the HTML reports.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In a maven project the target/site folder shall include those html reports unless specified otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to generate JaCoCo report as follows :

1. Configured JaCoCo as Java Agent
2. Restart the Server and do some transactions/give some load (in my case I ran a series of automated tests)
3. Stop the Server (This will actually generate the jacoco.exec file)
4. Create/Configure the Ant script and run it (This will read the jacoco.exec file and generate the html report). Refer : http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html

Even though my Project is a Maven project, I used ant script for the Report generation. I automated all the above steps using Bamboo and it made running and maintaining this Job easier.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the jacoco:report-aggregate goal with Maven.
You could refer this http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/report-aggregate-mojo.html

P.S. : However, when i had the same issue, I used Sonar to read the exec file that was generated. It gives much more than just code coverage.

Comment: I was getting this issue : [INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file. I actually have a profile where I had configured the Jacoco. So I'm running: "mvn -PprofileName jacoco:report" If I copy and paste the exec file in the location, it works. How do I specify a particular location of the dataFile in the mvn comman?

Comment: You could specify the property <jacoco.reportPath> path to the report </jacoco.reportPath> in the pom.xml  or specify it in the mvn command as -Djacoco.reportPath